# Javascript flipping the div with content

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page where there should be 2 rows, each containing two rectangular divs with content (image, h3 and paragraph). When clicking on the div, it has to flip in order to show its back content.

All the work is done with Bootstrap and the script is taken from 
https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/.

The matter is simple yet impossible for me: those two rows stay on top of one another. All I need is for them to stay on different rows and be responsive.

This is my HTML:

```
 <div class="container grid-container">  

        <div class="row">
            <div class="card-grid col-md-6">
                <div class="front">
                    <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
                    <h3>Front text</h3>
                    <p> ---  </p> 
                </div> 
                <div class="back">
                    <h2>Back text</h2>
                </div>  
             </div>       

            <div class="card-grid col-md-6">
                <div class="front">
                    <img src="images/2.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
                    <h3>Front text</h3>
                    <p> ---  </p> 
                </div> 
                <div class="back">
                    <h2>Back text</h2>
                </div>  
             </div>       

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="card-grid col-md-6">
                <div class="front">
                    <img src="images/3.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
                    <h3>Front text</h3>
                    <p> ---  </p> 
                </div> 
                <div class="back">
                    <h2>Back text</h2>
                </div>  
             </div>        

            <div class="card-grid col-md-6">
                <div class="front">
                    <img src="images/4.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
                    <h3>Front text</h3>
                    <p>  --- </p>  
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                    <h2>Back text</h2>
                </div>   
             </div>     

        </div>

    </div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
   .card-grid{
      perspective: 500px;
      position:relative;
      transform-style:preserve-3d;
    }

   .grid-container>.row>.card-grid>.front{
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
     backface-visibility: hidden;
     transform-style: preserve-3d;
     position:absolute;
     z-index:1;
     transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
     transform:rotateY(0deg);
    }

   .grid-container>.row>.card-grid>.back{
     transform:rotateY(-180deg);
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
     backface-visibility:hidden;
     transform-style:preserve-3d;
     position:absolute;
     z-index:0;
     transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
  }
```

About CSS: I tried to make classes `.front` and `.back` less specific, then I tried to override Bootstrap's CSS file by making them more specific. No change.

And my main JS script is this:

```
  $(function(){
    $(".card-grid").flip({
    trigger:"click"
    });
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

I think below code helps you
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nadimsajib/bhx8fqvm/
HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
<div class="row">
   <div id="card" class="card col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">   
    <div class="front"> 
     <img src="http://www.kiplinger.com/quiz/business/T049-S001-test-your-start-up-know-how/images/all-small-businesses-have-to-be-incorporated1.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
     <h3>Front text</h3>
     <p> -&#45;&#45;  </p>
    </div> 
    <div class="back">
     <h2>Back text</h2>
    </div> 
  </div>
<div style="height:500px;">

</div>
<div class="card col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"> 

    <div class="front"> 
      <img src="http://www.kiplinger.com/quiz/business/T049-S001-test-your-start-up-know-how/images/all-small-businesses-have-to-be-incorporated1.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
      <h3>Front text</h3>
      <p> -&#45;&#45;  </p>
   </div> 
   <div class="back">
     <h2>Back text</h2>
   </div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function($) {
   $(".card").flip(); 
});
```

Comment: @tornprince .. i think you change the <div class="row"> and use <div class="col-md-12"> .. it shows all your div one by one ..

Comment: Replaced. Nothing changed...Still sitting on top of one another.

Comment: I removed my script file with code lines above and divs are on different rows now. But nothing flips since that part is out.

Comment: I do. And as I said, if I don't put my triggers for the flip, those divs are on different rows, but once I right my triggers they stack on top of each other, like before.

Comment: @tornprince .. would you please check my answer again this is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nadimsajib/bhx8fqvm/

Comment: I appreciate your help very much! Tried everything that you wrote ( if I understood correctly, you've put an empty div just for the height, and it helped! ) but once I get to XS screen, two div on the same row just collapse one on another...